# Fitting a Lorentzian with lmfit to a histogram

Tags: python, matplotlib, data-analysis, curve-fitting, lmfit

I am currently trying to fit a Lorentzian using lmfit to my histogram and have code like this:

```
from scipy.stats import norm
import matplotlib.mlab as mlab
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
from matplotlib import colors
from matplotlib.ticker import PercentFormatter
from lmfit.models import LorentzianModel
import csv
data_initial = list()
data_floats = list()

#put data in a list
with open('pendumlum_data.csv', newline='') as csvfile:
    spamreader = csv.reader(csvfile, delimiter=' ', quotechar='|')
    for row in spamreader:
        data_initial.append(','.join(row))

for x in data_initial[1:]:
    y = float(x)
    data_floats.append(y)

#statistics
# mu = sum(data_floats)/len(data_floats)
# variance = sum([((x - mu) ** 2) for x in data_floats]) / len(data_floats)
# sigma = variance ** 0.5
mu, std = norm.fit(data_floats)
data = list()
for x in range(0,len(data_floats)):
    if data_floats[x] < mu + 2*std and data_floats[x] > mu - 2*std:
        data.append(data_floats[x])

print(data)
bins = 40
n, bins, patches = plt.hist(data, bins = bins, range=(mu-(2*std), mu+(2*std)), facecolor='green', edgecolor='black', alpha=0.6)
print(n)
print(mu)
print(bins[1:])
print(std)

xmin, xmax = plt.xlim()
x = np.linspace(xmin, xmax, 100)
mod = LorentzianModel()
pars = mod.make_params(amplitude=32, center=mu, sigma=std)
fit = mod.fit(n, pars, x=bins[1:])
print(fit.fit_report(min_correl=0.25))
#plt.plot(bins, fit, '--')
bincenters = 0.5*(bins[1:]+bins[:-1])
menStd = np.sqrt(n)
width = 0.02
plt.errorbar(bincenters, n, menStd, linestyle='None', fmt='.k')
plt.text(10,36,'Fitted Mean: ' + str(9.828) + " +/- " + str(0.004),horizontalalignment='left')
plt.text(10,34,'Fitted Std: ' + str(0.063) +' +/- '+ str(0.003),horizontalalignment='left')
plt.text(10,32,'Chi2/ndf:  ' + str(1.583),horizontalalignment='left')
plt.xlabel('g (m/s^2)')
plt.ylabel('Counts')
plt.title(r'Pendulum Data')

plt.subplots_adjust(left=0.15)
plt.show()
```

But the problem is I keep getting an error saying ValueError: x and y must have same first dimension, but have shapes (41,) and (1,). Does anyone know what I am doing wrong?

Comment: What are the values of `n, mu, std, bins`?

Comment: n = [ 0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  1.  1.  0.  1.  0.  4.  2.  3.  1.  0.  0.  5.  4.
 13. 32. 11.  4.  3.  2.  3.  2.  0.  0.  2.  1.  1.  1.  0.  0.  2.  0.
  2.  0.  0.  0.]

Comment: mu =9.833185185185185

Comment: bins = [ 8.33911621  8.41775142  8.49638663  8.57502184  8.65365704  8.73229225
  8.81092746  8.88956267  8.96819788  9.04683309  9.1254683   9.20410351
  9.28273872  9.36137393  9.44000914  9.51864435  9.59727956  9.67591477
  9.75454998  9.83318519  9.91182039  9.9904556  10.06909081 10.14772602
 10.22636123 10.30499644 10.38363165 10.46226686 10.54090207 10.61953728
 10.69817249 10.7768077  10.85544291 10.93407812 11.01271333 11.09134853
 11.16998374 11.24861895 11.32725416 11.40588937]

Comment: std = 0.7863520936265712

Comment: Your script is incomplete and will not run, so we do not know what you have actually done.  The error message tells you that `bin[1:]` and `n` have different shapes.  Both are undefined in your script, making it impossible to know what you are doing.   Include a minimal but complete example that shows the problem and the exact (unedited) output, including any error messages.   Posting numbers into comments is not useful.

Comment: Okay I updated my question to have the whole script. Thanks. The csv file has 111 numbers separated by commas ranging from 7-14 (measuring the value of free fall acceleration).

Comment: I also commented out the line giving me trouble which is where I plot the fit. The fit results get printed in the terminal (chi squared, fitted mean, etc.)

Comment: You might want `plt.plot(bins, fit.best_fit, 'r--')`

Comment: Okay I tried that and got this "raise ValueError(f"x and y must have same first dimension, but "
ValueError: x and y must have same first dimension, but have shapes (41,) and (40,)"

Comment: Yes, the message is saying that `y` and `x` must have the same length and that your values for `y` (`n`) and your values for `x` (`bins[1:]`) have lengths of 41 and 40.   Do you see why that could happen and what you might do to investigate further and then fix it?